# How to get the value of row after onDoneSpinning Cocos2d-iphone

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I'm following this demo https://github.com/fidgetware/CCPickerView. 
but i want to know that how to get the value of row after spinning.
any help ?!

Answer (score 0):

I have never used the class but having a look it looks like you can call the method.

```
- (NSInteger)selectedRowInComponent:(NSInteger)component;
```

There is also a delegate method for `onDoneSpinning` which I see you have mentioned in your title.

Comment: above method is use with UIPickerView.though i tried it with CCPickerView,but failed :(